# MVC - Data annotations for controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations, model-binding

Can you please explain how to apply data annotations to custom control?

Example:
Model

```
public class ToDo
{
    [Required]
    public int ListId { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<form action="/Todo/Submit" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="txtListId" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

How can I ensure that data annotation is used when user doesn't enter anything in txtListId?

I know that in my custom model binder - I can either use bindingcontext.valueprovider to get attemptedvalue and check if it is nullorempty and add error to modelstate or use try - catch block to catch formatexception and invalidate modelstate.

But in above methods - data annotation is not really used.

Please guide me in this regard.

Thank you,
Sasha

Comment: make ListId nullable. then also be sure that you are showing the ValidationMessageFor also (if you decide to do so).

Answer (score 1):

Using the right field would be a good start. You've specified that `ListId` is required, but you're never using `ListId`, but rather `txtListId`. You should really use Razor helpers to generate your inputs:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ListId)
```

Short of that, just name your input properly:

```
<input type="text" name="ListId" />
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. Scenario is - What if the control name is not matching with model property name.

Answer (score 0):

To display the validation message, assuming that you are using Razor view engine and your view is bound to the model **Todo**, you must use the following line:

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.ListId) %>
```

This will cause the validation message to be displayed on the page. Hence, your view must look something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ListId)
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.ListId) %>
```

Also, in the controller, you need to have a check for validating the model state:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    //take some action
    //maybe, add to DB or whatever
}
else
    return view(); // render the view again
```